# Constraint with regexp

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, oracle11g, constraints

I am currently trying to create a regular expresion to use in my Oracle database constraints' that is able to check if all the words of a string starts with an uppercase. I already tried to use functions like initcap, but it really doesn't work as expected, because it gives an error when I try to insert values that contains a letter like "ñ" or an acent. Could you please help me?

Comment: I don't understand your description of the problem. You want to check that the first letter of every word is uppercase. What about the **rest** of the word - can it be in any case? If so (and you didn't say anything to the contrary), then why would you even try `initcap`? Obviously that would fail on a word like IBM. Then, you mention `initcap` fails on accented words. How so? I don't think that's true. If in fact you want all words to be "initcap" (meaning IBM will fail, since it isn't initcap), then indeed `initcap` in the constraint will work perfectly fine. Please clarify.

Comment: This constraint is going to be used to check if real people names matches the format of a name (for example, Antonio Pérez have to work, neither Antonio pérez, because the last one isn't using an uppercase for the first letter of every word). I have tried that constraint, and it doesn't work for me, i don't know why it doesn't let any name to come in, because when I put "Antonio Pérez", it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a check constraint and a regex, like so:

```
alter table mytable
    add constraint myconstraint
    check (not regexp_like(mycol, '(^|\W)[a-z]'))
```

Regexp `(^|\W)[A-Z]` means: the beginning of the string or a non-word character followed by an lower case value. `not regexp_like(...)` forbids such pattern.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d9ff5621b44e7dec1c8425e85f517999)**

---

As commented by @kfinity, you can also use regex `(^|\W)[[:lower:]]`, that should properly trap special upper characters.

Comment: Great, now need to be extended to "all the words of a string"

Comment: I might suggest `[[:upper:]]` instead of `[A-Z]` to catch things like `Â` or `Ç`

Comment: @kfinity: it looks like `[[:upper:]]` does not trap `Â`: [db fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=14c24780dad4459a391f9e5f4dd6e3db)

Comment: @GMB: that may be locale-specific.

Comment: @GMB (i didn't downvote) that db fiddle is using US7ASCII as the local charset, it's inserting garbage characters. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3dd1aeda471b667a3c3e329ca67a5b1b

Comment: @kfinity: ok I understand... I updated my asnwer to add your suggestion, thanks!

Comment: Could you please explain why are you using the operator NOT? I think that the regular exp will return a True value if all the words starts with an uppercase letter, if not, it will return False. If you use the operator NOT, you will invert that.

Comment: @Trickv2: I partly misread your question, just fixed the regexp now. The idea with `not regexp_like(...)` is to forbid insert of values that match the regex.

Comment: @GMB I think it is easier just to do "check (regexp_like(mycol, '(^|\W)[A-Z]'))", without using the NOT operator, but it works anyways! Thank you so much mate. Just more one question, will it work for all the words of the string or just for the first one?

Comment: @Trickv2 - What you say is "easier" is not equivalent to the final solution GMB has posted. The "not" version - using "lower" - will prevent ANY word that begins with a lowercase letter, anywhere in the string. Your "easier" version will allow any string that has at least one word that begins with an uppercase, no matter what else may exist in the string. That's not the same thing. GMB's current solution (same as Gordon Linnoff's) will do what you seem to want.

Comment: @Trickv2: see the explanation from mathguy about why you need `not regexp_like(...)` (thanks mathguy). And, to answer your other question, yes, this checks for every word, not only for the first one. You can see that in the db fiddle that I linked in my answer.

Comment: @GMB well, I have been trying it in a real oracle and it doesn't make the job... in the page that u sent me, it works perfectly when when I use my oracle 11g, I can for example enter values like ' hello'

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the check constraint that you want is more like this:

```
check (not regexp_like(mycol, '(^|\W)[[:lower:]]'))
```